# Listview with with checkbox - searching

Tags: java, android, listview

The problem is that when after searching when I check checkbox (my search item is in 1st position) and remove search it will check on position 1 not in the position that I found. How to change this?

```
    public static List<String> osComponent= new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listViewComponent = (ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listViewComponent.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, osComponent);
    listViewComponent.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

I adds photos to show what's going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @pskink look on the pictures. The problem is that I check "banana" not "wino" when searching but after remove I have check the "wino" not "banan".

Comment: @pskink no I get date from sqlite do ArrayList and then add this list to ListView and search in ListView. And using only this code higher.

Comment: @pskink really thanks bro. that works perfectly.

Comment: @pskink but how to get in setOnItemClickListener text from adapter from your code? https://pastebin.com/raw/GFExg5RX Something like this `listViewComponent.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println(and here get e.g banana or whatever I click
);
            }
        });

Comment: `parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)`

Comment: but why would you like to get a text if you have an id of clicked item?

Comment: @pskink because I want get text from chosen item and pass this text e.g "banana" to next activity. But when I do as you say it returns me this: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@6f3da74

Comment: it returns the right thing: try to see its content by calling `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow` method - but actually what do you want to do with that text? isn't the ID of table row a better solution?

Comment: @pskink soory for so many questions. But ok, so how to get the ID of table row in onitemclicklistener? Like that parent.getAdapter().getItemId(position)?

Comment: you have it as a last parameter of onItemClick method